# Removing words containing a certain substring

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

So I'm making a function to receive in a word corpus, and then spit out a cleaned product:

```
corpus_creater <- function(corpus){
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
}
```

This works great for the most part, however when I look at the resulting word cloud I generated I notice one thing that stands out:
the word cloud includes random words that have the term "html" in them.

I figure I can fix this by simply adding a line in the function that removes any word that contains the substring "http", but I can't for the life of get around to doing that, and all the existing answers I've found seem to have to do with replacing a substring, or removing only that substring.

What I want to do is:
if a substring is a part of the word, then remove that entire word.

Word Cloud code I use to generate the word cloud from the corpus:

```
color_scheme <- brewer.pal(9,"YlGnBu")
color_scheme <- color_scheme[-(1:4)]
set.seed(103)
wordcloud(words = manu_corpus_final, max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, 
          rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=color_scheme)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm trying to integrate that into my function and it's returning the error "'names' attribute [2000] must be the same length as the vector [3]"

I added a `corpus <- corpus[grep("http", corpus, invert = TRUE)]` line at the end, is that the wrong way to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are directly getting corpus as input, you could extract the `content` of corpus using `sapply` and then remove the document from the corpus which has the required string.

You could integrate it into your function in the following way :

```
corpus_creater <- function(corpus){
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
   #Added the below line
   corpus <- corpus[-grep("http", sapply(corpus, `[`, 1))]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it seems to get rid of the error. However when I attempt to generate my word cloud with the code (I added the wordcloud's code in the OP), it doesn't generate one, apparently because of the NULL value. Is there a way to remove the word and not make it null for wordcloud purposes?? The err is: `Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x): no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch Can you try the updated version of the answer?

Comment: That works gorgeously now, thank you so much!!!

The wordcloud had a lot of "http" before but now they're all gone!